# Android : WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder for FB - the request is succesfullly going but i need to change it as "xxx "Invites you to try

Tags: android, facebook, request

I am creating the request dialog using the Android FB SDK 3.7, i am able to send the request to the friends, and its succesfully going as as "XXX" has sent you the Request as Notification in FB.
But i need to change this Notification request Message as "XXX" has Invites you to try my app.
and i am trying to include deeplinking with this.
i ahve already tried 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/link-to-your-native-app/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
Please provide some inputs how do i can change this.

Comment: what you have tried now?

Comment: i have tried this dialog and the request is going fine with this WebDialog requestsDialog = (
        new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))